# Can't Disable PHPs X-Powered-By header

Tags: php, apache, fpm

I am running apache on Centos 7. I have php 7.0.33 installed and I am using FPM. I created a php page and used php_info to find the location of the ini file.

I found the `php.ini` in `/etc/opt/remi/php70/php.ini` and I set `expose_php = Off`. I restarted apache, but it has not made any difference. The header is still showing up when I refresh the page `x-powered-by: PHP/7.0.33`

Because this is the FPM implementation, is there somewhere other than the php.ini that I need to modify this setting? I found an apache conf file called php.conf and inside I see it using  `SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9007"` Do I need to restart this fcgi process?

If so, how do I figure out how to do this? I tried to see if php-fpm was a command line option and it is, but this is for php 5. It isn't the new version.

Comment: `php_info` ? do you mean `phpinfo();`  ?  anyway, what do you get from ```sudo sh -c 'find / -iname "*.ini" -print0 | xargs --null --max-args=1 cat | grep -i expose ';```  ?  (PS there's a much better way to write that, just can't think of it atm)

Comment: @hanshenrik this worked. it found 3 .ini files. only one of which has expose set to off. The problem is the query didnt list the file path so i dont know where to find the file to modify it

Comment: that's a good start. just run `sudo find / -iname "*.ini" 2>/dev/null` , what do you get?  alternatively `-iname "*php*.ini"`